# Create a shortcut with parameters added to the program path

Tags: batch-file, shortcut, wsh

Here's the code, it works if I right click on the new .Lnk and remove the quotes
from `"C:\Windows\System32\control.exe /name Microsoft.Windowsupdate"`
to `C:\Windows\System32\control.exe /name Microsoft.Windowsupdate`

```
echo off
Cls
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Weekly Maintenance\Windows Update.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\control.exe /name Microsoft.Windowsupdate" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
pause
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify? What *exactly* is the problem you are seeing? The behavior you are expecting versus what is actually happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation on [WshShortcut.TargetPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67(v=vs.84).aspx) says:

> This property is for the shortcut's target path only.
>   Any arguments to the shortcut must be placed in the Argument's property.

The fragment of a working code:

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\control.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Arguments = "/name Microsoft.Windowsupdate" >> %SCRIPT%
```

And the entire fixed code:

```
@echo off
Cls
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Weekly Maintenance\Windows Update.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\control.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Arguments = "/name Microsoft.Windowsupdate" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Works perfectly I'm going to put the full code here for everyone else